# using inotifywait for nginx restart

Tags: bash, nginx, inotifywait

I want to use inotifywait to restart nginx when configuration changes are detected in a script. The problem is that if I run it in daemon mode it keep restarting the nginx.

The script looks like this:

```
while inotifywait -d -o /var/log/bootstrap.log --format '%T %:e %w' --timefmt '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S' -e modify,create,delete,move,attrib $(find -L /etc/nginx -type f)
do
  NGX_STATUS=$(nginx -t 2>&1)
  NGX_CFG_STATUS=$(echo $NGX_STATUS | grep successful)
  if [[ $(echo $?) == 0 ]]; then
      /etc/init.d/nginx restart
  else
    echo $NGX_STATUS | tee -a /var/log/bootstrap.log
  fi
done
```

Note: This script is part of the docker entrypoint script.

Comment: What is in `/var/log/bootstrap.log`?

Comment: grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script
 * Restarting nginx nginx

Answer (score 0):

You can try the script below. It checks to see if pyinotify is installed before doing it's thing.

```
 import sys
 import pip
 def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])
 try:
    import pyinotify
 except ImportError:
    print 'pyinotify is not installed, installing it now!'
    install('pyinotify')
 finally:
   import pyinotify,subprocess
   def onChange(ev):
     cmd = ['/bin/systemctl', 'reload', 'nginx.service']
     subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()
   wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
   wm.add_watch('/etc/nginx/nginx.conf', pyinotify.IN_MODIFY,    onChange)
   notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)
   notifier.loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put `inotifywait` in daemon mode (the `-d` option), it forks to a background process and returns. By calling it from a `while` loop, you are creating many `inotifywait` daemons which are running in the background.

Don't pass `-d` and it will work.

Comment: Any idea how to trigger the script with the -d option? Thing is that without the -d the docker will not start the script.

Comment: You want to run the whole script in the background, not just `inotifywait`. I don't know how to do that with docker. That would be a good separate question.